# SQL query to count total ocurrences of values in one column and relative occurrence in another column

Tags: mysql, sql

This is my first post, so any general corrections to format/content are also welcome. I'm relatively new to SQL.

Say I have a database which collects test results from an classification evaluation. I know what the expected outcome is for each test. I also have a column indicating whether the test was successful, ie the expected value returned matched the expected value. It looks something like this:

```
Expected_Result   Result    Success
   A                  A     True
   A                  B     False
   B                  B     True
   A                  A     True
   B                  A     False
```

I know I can return the total occurrences of each expected type with`SELECT Expected_Result, COUNT(Expected_Result) FROM Evaluation_Results GROUP BY Expected_Result`.
I  know how to count the number of false detections for a specific expected outcome with `SELECT  COUNT(*) FROM Evaluation_Results WHERE Success = 'True' AND Expected_Result = 'A'`

Where I'm struggling is combining the two. I would like the query to return a list of all distinct expected results, the total of each, the count of successful results, and the percentage of the total, like so:

```
Expected_Result     Total   Num_Successful  Success_Rate
A                    3          2             66.67
B                    2          1             50.00
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a CASE expression to perform a condition check during aggregation. A case statement identifies a conditional outcome. For instance you could use:

```
select evaluation_result
, count(*) AS total
, sum(case when success='true' and result='a' then 1 else 0 end) AS num_successful
, sum(case when success='true' and result='a' then 1 else 0 end)/count(*) AS success_rate
from evaluation_results group by evaluation_result;
```

Basically what's happening there is you're taking a count(*) of all grades, a sum() of a 1 or 0 based on a conditional outcome, then performing the ratio math. There's no need for a join here. The [CASE Expression](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/case.html) is a powerful conditional statement which can be used in so many diverse ways.

Or for a more flexible solution have a look at this:

```
select evaluation_result
, count(*) AS total
, sum(case when success='true' and result=evaluation_result then 1 else 0 end) AS num_successful
, sum(case when success='true' and result=evaluation_result then 1 else 0 end)/count(*) AS success_rate
from evaluation_results group by evaluation_result;
```

Comment: Case expression, not case statement.

Comment: The success_rate is returned as 0 for all rows? Also why use result when the Success column has already compared it to the expected_result?

Comment: Accepted as answer, but I removed the 'result=evaluation_result' clause in the summation, and multiplied the sum by 100.0 before division for % success rate. Perhaps you should edit your answer. Thank you.

Comment: I'm glad it worked for you - the success rate is returned as a ratio (which is typically how I prefer to look at percentages) So my apologies for leaving that out.

Comment: don't  yo think it is time consuming?

Comment: @RakeshKumar When you refer to time consuming what precisely do you mean? Are you concerned for the SQL query's performance?

Answer (score 0):

You can use self join if table is same like.

```
SELECT distinct e.Expected_Result, COUNT(Expected_Result), sum(e1.columns name), avg(e1.column name)
FROM Evaluation_Results e
    left join Evaluation_Results e1 on e1.col=e.col
GROUP BY e.Expected_Result
```

Comment: Why SELECT DISTINCT? The GROUP BY returns no duplicates.

Answer (score -1):

Use this simple Query and check for the result..

```
select Expected_Result, count(Expected_Result) Total,
sum(IF ('True' = Success, 1, 0) ) Num_Successful, 
avg(IF ('True' = Success, 1, 0 )) Success_Rate   
from Evaluation_Results group by Expected_Result
```